# NVIDIA - frozen screen on laptop but works with external monitors

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, xorg, gnome, nvidia

I'd like your help cause I already dug the whole documentation and my logs to try to find out what's going on. I'm using a ThinkPad X1 Extreme Gen 2 Laptop with two external ThinkVision monitors. To make the monitors render something, I had to install NVIDIA, here's my configuration:

```
export __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1
export __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD_PROVIDER=NVIDIA-G0
export __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia
export __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only
```

OpenGL and Prime with offload are enabled. My Intel and NVIDIA bus ids are correctly set. The external monitors are working just fine, but when I unplug them, everything freezes. The logs from `journalctl` don't say much:

```
May 09 16:11:08 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:08 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
May 09 16:11:08 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:11:08 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:08 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:08 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
May 09 16:11:08 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
May 09 16:11:08 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:08 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:13 j.calvinn87 systemd[1594]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
May 09 16:11:25 j.calvinn87 systemd[1594]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
May 09 16:11:46 j.calvinn87 systemd[1594]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 systemd-udevd[15791]: card0: Process '/bin/bash -c 'mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia0 c $(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 0'' failed with exit code 1.
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 systemd-udevd[15791]: card0: Process '/bin/bash -c 'mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia0 c $(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 0'' failed with exit code 1.
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x12d8350] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x24e6f30] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x24eade0] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x24e7320] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x24eaa60] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x782a730] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:11:49 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x24ea6e0] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 systemd-udevd[15800]: card0: Process '/bin/bash -c 'mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia0 c $(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 0'' failed with exit code 1.
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 systemd-udevd[15800]: card0: Process '/bin/bash -c 'mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia0 c $(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 0'' failed with exit code 1.
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): connected
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): connected
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-1: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off, ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}"
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 .gsd-media-keys[1819]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): connected
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:11:59 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x12d8350] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x24e6f30] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x24eade0] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x24e7320] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x24eaa60] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x12d8350] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x24e6f30] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x24eade0] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x24e7320] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x24eaa60] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x782a730] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x24ea6e0] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): connected
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:00 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 systemd-udevd[15800]: card0: Process '/bin/bash -c 'mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia0 c $(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 0'' failed with exit code 1.
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): connected
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): connected
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): connected
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:01 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-1: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off, ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off, ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}"
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-1: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +1920+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off, ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off, ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}"
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 .gsd-media-keys[1819]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): connected
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): connected
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): connected
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): connected
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x12d8350] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x24e6f30] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x24eade0] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x12d8350] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x24e6f30] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x24eade0] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x24e7320] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 .gnome-shell-wr[1658]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x24eaa60] is on because it needs an allocation.
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): connected
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-0): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): connected
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Lenovo Group Limited LEN T24d-10 (DFP-1): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 09 16:12:02 j.calvinn87 libexec/gdm-x-session[1611]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 09 16:12:10 j.calvinn87 systemd-udevd[15849]: card0: Process '/bin/bash -c 'mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia0 c $(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 0'' failed with exit code 1.
```

The logs are being registered when I unplug and plug the monitors. GDM is working fine, even without the external monitors.

ANY help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you boot the laptop from USB, e.g., WinRE or Ubuntu Live, does it display correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exactly problem today

I generated the `xorg.conf` with `nvidia-xconfig` but before doing that, I did a backup from the previous file.

The xorg.conf generated by the new version of `nvidia-utils` (currently using 515.57-1) dosen't put that extra Section.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "modesetting"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
EndSection
```

And in the `ServerLayout` Section, there's a new line `Inactive "Device1"`

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    Inactive       "Device1"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection
```

Maybe this isn't the best/right solution, but it worked for me, and it was generated by an old version of `nvidia-xconfig`